# Remove elements whose id name contains certain string

Tags: javascript

I want to remove all elements (suppose they're all divs) whose id name contains the string `bs`. How to do this via javascript regardless of they are nested elements or not? (not jquery)

```
<div id="new_bs_add"></div>

<div id="bsremove"></div>

<div id="somethingelse"></div>

... and many more
```

Comment: Why 'not jquery'? What you are asking for (advanced selection) is one of the core jQuery features.

Comment: Because it's not applicable in my case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No jQuery, but if there's support for CSS3 selectors you can go for

```
var rem = document.querySelectorAll("[id*='bs']"), i = 0;
for (; i < rem.length; i++)
    rem[i].parentNode.removeChild(rem[i]);
```

Otherwise, just go for this slight edit of VisioN's solution:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("[id]");
for (var i = 0, len = divs.length; i < len; i++) {
    var div = divs[i];
    if (div.id.indexOf("bs") > -1) {
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    }
}
```

Comment: the first answer isn't portable and the second still has VisioN's original bug in it.

Comment: @Alnitak Actually not. `querySelectorAll` works (for some reason) fine with forward iteration: http://jsfiddle.net/c4ewU/1/.

Comment: About the first one, how to select elements `if id contains bs Or other string`?

Comment: @Alnitak Yeah, I've also figured it out. So maybe backward iteration by `NodeList` with basic check of `id` property is the best solution here, both fast and cross browser.

Comment: @VisioN or just go forward and ensure you don't iterate over deleted elements.  That's in theory more efficient because it removes entire branches in one go, rather than working from the leaf nodes back up.

Comment: @Alnitak Agree, it will make less iterations in special cases when removable parent has removable child(ren), otherwise it does the same.

Comment: @Alnitak That makes me remind me *a little* of an user who whined about an answer of mine that made use of `innerHTML`, saying that wasn't standard... in 2012. IE doesn't support CSS3 selectors in `querySelectorAll`, ok, but I usually either support their users with jQuery or let them die in the Middle Ages. It's actually up to what OP wants, fortunately has plenty of answers to choose here.

Comment: @MaxArt fair point, but it's still good to point out incompatibilities that the OP may not be aware of. Hell, I don't code for IE either!

Comment: @Alnitak Yes, indeed I pointed that out in the first line of my answer :) And fortunately, I managed to make the company where I work switch from IE to Chrome as the primary platform of web development ;)

Comment: @MaxArt lucky you.   BTW, does "CSS3 support" === "qSA support" ?

Comment: @Alnitak Sadly no, because qSA works with the selectors supported by the browser. The main difference is actually IE8, which supports CSS 2.1 selectors but nothing more, including `*=`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just do   `div.style.display = 'none';` instead of deleting an element though I understand the OP wants to remove an element.

Answer (score 4):

*Pure JavaScript:*

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i = divs.length; i;) {
    var div = divs[--i];
    if (div.id.indexOf("bs") > -1) {
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    }
}
```

As an example, in *jQuery* it is one line:

```
$("div[id*='bs']").remove();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/c4ewU/

Comment: there's a serious bug in this code, and another probable bug that I'm still checking out.

Comment: Indeed, if you remove an element, then the collection will be modified. You have to `i--` when you remove the div. Or iterate backwards. This doesn't happen using `querySelectorAll`, which returns a static collection.

Comment: @Alnitak Regarding iteration I agree with MaxArt, backward loop will do the thing. However, there is no real need in check of `parentNode`, since `<div>` elements will always have at least `<body>`. Or are there other problems I skipped?

Comment: @VisioN I was thinking of a `div` inside a `div`, which would cause problems if the outer div is removed first.  Going backwards probably fixes that, though, since the inner div will always get removed first.

Answer (score 3):

The most portable method to obtain a list of elements is `document.getElementsByTagName`.  However the resulting list is a *live node list* which means that if you modify the document, the list changes too!

There are two solutions for this.  One is to take a copy of the list:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var copy = [].slice.call(nodes, 0);   // take a copy

for (var i = 0, n = copy.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var d = copy[i];
    if (d.parentNode && d.id.indexOf('bs') >= 0) {
        d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
    }
}
```

The second is to either work through the list backwards, or ensure that you don't advance the iterator if you modify the list.  This takes the latter approach:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; /* blank */ ) {
    var d = nodes[i];
    if (d.id.indexOf('bs') >= 0) {
        d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
    } else {
        ++i; // iterate forward
    }
}
```

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName will not get you any “orphaned” nodes, because the nodes have to be in the document. And you don’t need to make a “copy” if you just loop over the nodeList in reverse order, because then the changing length is of no concern.

Comment: @CBroe iterating forward could get you an orphaned node if you had a div inside a div, but I think going backwards solves that problem too.

Comment: As you already said, nodeLists are “live” – so if you remove an outer node, the inner node is gone as well … so no “orphan” there. Only the length would change, so one would have to keep that dynamic in the loop condition.

Answer (score 0):

try this code
first get all elements contain certain text (here 'bs')

```
var matches = [];
var searchElements = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].children;
for(var i = 0; i < searchElements.length; i++) {
  if(searchElements[i].tagName == 'DIV') {
    if(searchElements[i].id.indexOf('bs') != -1) {
       matches.push(searchElements[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Then delete them from body of html

```
for(var i = 0;i<matches.length; i++)
    matches[i].parentNode.removeChild(matches[i]);
```

If you remove them in the first loop, there will be some tags will not deleted as the children array length is decreased each time you delete a node. So the better way to get them all in an external array and then delete them.